# mp4 video only loads when chrome dev tools are open

Tags: html, css, mp4

The video i have set for background of the div will only start playing when i refresh the page and the chrome dev tools are open.

html:

```
<div id="videoDiv">
<div id="videoBlock">
<img src="" id="vidSub">
<video preload="preload" id="vid1" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop">
<source src="images/solPromo.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>
</video>
```

css:

```
#vid1 {
    display: none;
}

#vidSub {
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    max-width:100%;     
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {
    #vid1 {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        padding-top: 480px;
        z-index: 1;

    }
    #vidSub {
        display: none;
    }
}

#videoDiv {
    width: 100%; 
    max-width:992px; 
    margin:auto; 
    display:block;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    background: transparent;
}
```

my thought was with the z-index but i have switched them both and neither had any effect on the loading of the video w/o the dev tools opened

Comment: Because CSS doesn't do anything over the load of the video, you should look at the preload attr you have defined. It looks it works: https://jsfiddle.net/jpmttoLa/

Comment: @z3nth10n ive set it to both "auto" and "metadata" and neither have made any effect to the video. Is there something else i can set it as?

Comment: Which is your exactly problem then?

Comment: The problem is when the site loads there is no video in the background of the div. When i open chrome dev tools and just hit refresh, the video loads and works just fine.

Comment: I don't have this problem, the video just load fine, have you tested another browser?

Comment: yeah ive tried in both safari and google chrome. if you want to check out the site for yourself: http://goodomens.com/
scroll down to the bottom to the contact form, this is where the video needs to play behind the form

Comment: But the problem here is with the JQuery that is changing the visibility to the `videoBlock` element.

Comment: is that a simple fix? im working off of a template so i did not write the JQuery nor do i know how to change that

Answer (score 4):

This is not so much related to dev tools, but to new Chrome browser "[Video Autoplay Policy](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes)" changes. Chrome stopped autoplaying unmuted videos.

Comment: could it be anything else? I have same problem with these props in the video tag > autoplay loop muted playsinline